# Spectre-mitigated libraries are required for this project, EVEN after i disabled it in options?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, wdk, spectre

I tried  DISABLING the Spectre mitigation from the code generation in option, but i still cannot compile a simple hello world driver, why? how can i stop this message and just compile a simple hello world without needing to install these libraries? i tried to even install them using individual components, but there are 100 different versions in there.. tried installing the latest verison but didnt help..

I am using the latest version of visual studio 2019. SDK and WDK are both installed.

this is happening after i made a mistake of upgrading visual studio, everything was fine in my 2017 visual studio..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after you install those libraries( **which is necessary** )  you can go to `project Property`  then `C/C++` the `Code Generation` look down you going to find Spectre mitigation then you can **enable** it or **disable** it, t***his won't work if you didn't install those libraries which is necessary for the last update*** of visual studio

Comment: why the hell do i need to install the libraries if i disabled the   option?

Comment: will that's how you would make it work otherwise it won't compile